# Setting up a webserver

Tags: windows-server-2003, php, web-server

How do I make from my OS WindowsServer2003 an internetwebserver,
e.g. with my own PHP forum on it?

Answer (score 5):

There are several options you can take:

1. [Install IIS and PHP5](http://www.videotutorialzone.com/web-technologies/php/installing-php5-on-windows-2003-and-iis6.html) then install [phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com/)
2. [Install Apache](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-the-Apache-Web-Server-on-a-Windows-PC) and PHP5, then install [phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com/)
3. Use a pre-created [WAMP stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP).

Which one will depend on your experience, and requirements.

Answer (score 1):

While I do understand you are on Windows Server 2003, you may consider an upgrade to Windows Server 2008 and IIS7 for its support of PHP. I ran it for a while and thought it worked great, although ultimately went to asp.net for various reasons. Of course from there you will have to install your forum software after PHP is setup.